# Understanding Wikipedia Raabe's test proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> I am having a hard time understanding the following proof on Wikipedia. This is the second question I post regarding steps in the proof.

[image]

**Question:**

**1)** When it is proven for $R<1$ that $a_{n+1}\geqslant \frac{ca_{N}}{n^R}$. The series are said to be divergent because $a_{n+1}\geqslant 0$ since $\frac{ca_{N}}{n^R}$ is bigger than zero.

**2)** What is being used in the second part of the proof? How can $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ become $O(1)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) No, it's not divergent because $a_{n++1}\ge0$, that's nonsense. It's divergent because $\sum1/n^R$ is divergent for $0<R<1$.

(2) The $O(\frac1{n^2})$ did not "become" $O(1)$. We had a sequence of equations, with error term $O(1/n^2)$. We *added* those equations. The error term in the sum is the sum of the error terms. Since $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, the error term in the sum is $O(1)$.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I understood point 1), but I have questions regarding 2). How does the $(1+\frac{R}{n}+...+\frac{R}{N})\geqslant cn^R$ fit the proof of the theorem. Does it prove the reverse inequality which by the comparison test proves the series converge for $R>1$?

Comment: The inequality in the question you just asked does not appear anywhere in the proof. The inequality you meant to ask about is used in the next paragraph - try reading that and thinking about what it says.

Comment: Thanks! However I am not aware of what is an error. I thought that the equality $\frac{R}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})=\log(1+\frac{R}{n})$ meant the limit to infinity, that in the limit they would be equal. But you talk about an error. Could you tell me what is it? And direct me to potential links about it?

Comment: Saying $\log(1+R/n)=R/n+O(1/n^2)$ means this: $\log(1+R/n)=R/n+E_n$, _where_ $|E_n|\le c/n^2$. Hence $\sum\log(1+R/n)=\sum R/n + E$, where $E=\sum E_n$. Since $|E_n\le c/n^2$ this shows that $|E|\le c$ (for a different value of $c$.) And saying $\sum(1+R/n)=\sum R/n+E$ where $|E|\le c$ is exactly what it means to say $\sum(1+R/n)=\sum R/n+O(1)$.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand why you write $\log(1+R/n)=R/n+O(1/n^2)$. Why is $O(1/n^2)$? And not other term? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroGomes Do you know Taylor's Theorem? That implies that $\log(1+t)=t+O(t^2)$ as $t\to0$. So $\log(1+R/n)=R/n+O(R^2/n^2)$, and since $R$ is fixed that's the same as $R/n+O(1/n^2)$.

Comment: Do you mean Taylor series?

Comment: @PedroGomes No,I mean Taylor's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** We have series with positive terms, and $\frac{ca_N}{n^R}$ diverges if $R\le 1$, so they use the comparison test.

Comment: You're right. Actually  I focused on question 2), not on its source in the proof. I agree my answer for this point is irrelevant, and I'll remove it.